# Limiting nproc in an upstart job

Tags: upstart

What exactly does the stanza

```
limit nproc 20 20
```

in an Upstart job do?

I've read the documentation here (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#limit), and it seems like it would limit nproc for any process related to the job. However, I don't see this effect when I've added this to my job's conf file - in this specific case, I've confirmed that my test job's single process was able to fork more than 20 child processes. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [man page for setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) (which Upstart uses for the limit stanza internally) states that processes are limited for the user id. My best guess is that the user id is root by default, and the resource limit does not work for root because that does not make any sense.